# Google Sheets - Sequential List of Staff off between 2 dates

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, formula

I have a list of days when staff are on holiday on Google Sheets. I have the to and from day.

```
NAME    FIRST       LAST

NAME 1  01/02/22    10/02/22

NAME 2  02/02/22    03/02/22

NAME 3  01/02/22    05/02/22

NAME 4  03/05/22    06/05/22
```

I would like a formula that can take a whole page of this and would like to list all of the days in order with the name for example:

```
NAME 1  01/02/22

NAME 1  02/02/22

NAME 1  03/02/22

NAME 1  04/02/22

NAME 1  05/02/22

NAME 1  ...

... 

NAME 2  02/02/22

NAME 2  03/02/22

NAME 3  01/02/22

NAME 3  02/02/22

... ...

... ...
```

I've worked through examples I can find online, and through Stack Overflow but can't find the exact formula I need.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF(A1:A="",,IF(
 SEQUENCE(1, MAX(DAYS(C1:C, B1:B)+1), 0)>=DAYS(C1:C, B1:B)+1,, A1:A&"×"&B1:B+
 SEQUENCE(1, MAX(DAYS(C1:C, B1:B)+1), 0)))), "×"), "where Col2 is not null", ))
```

[image]

Comment: When I put that, I get : Error
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col2 . I tried changing Col2 to B but get the same thing. Thanks

Comment: @SSheets can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: I'm off home shortly but will send tomorrow if that is ok.